# Bundling MySQL with an application

Tags: mysql, web-applications

There are alot of applications like MAMP, WAMP, etc. That come with a version of mysql that needs no installation and can be turned on and off easily. I am trying to create a web based application that will use a mysql database, where do you get mysql to bundle and how is it done so the user doesn't have to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get it mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

you can used php, ruby (rubyonrails) or java for developed application. in the case php install xampp.

Answer (score 0):

MAMP, WAMP, etc. all have a bunch of configuration that is already set up for them. Essentially they've installed MySQL and everything else included under a single directory that doesn't rely on anything outside that directory and then zipped it up together. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but that really seems like overkill. May I suggest checking out [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/)? It's designed for bundling and embedding and will be quite a bit easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Are you truly creating a Web Based app or are you wanting to create a desktop application using web scripting languages?

If you are creating a web app, you shouldn't need to bundle MySQL since when you deploy to your hosting environment it should already be in place.  If you truly need to package everything you'd be best off offering your software as a virtual machine appliance with the appropriate services already configured and running.

If you are creating a desktop app, that's a whole other issue.