# MySQL bundled within an NPM app

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, npm, electron

The idea is to bundle the MySQL database within the npm app. The reason behind this is because the app is intended to run as a stand-alone desktop application built using Electron and, of course, many other modules.

So far, all of my searches for a MySQL database module only leads to the drivers. All other tutorials talk about the typical web app set up wherein the MySQL db is installed in the server. A comment from another post discussed how to set up MySQL db in server and just mentioned that [if it's a desktop app, it's a whole other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7166050/2511541). I want to know if there is a way to do this or if it isn't possible at all.

Comment: so not only did you use a full server+browser+runtime to make an application, now you're also shipping MySQL instead of using Sqlite3 or something more suitable for applications, not trying to be rude or something, but your software is a fat mammoth

Comment: Yes I also figured that so I decided to use Lovefield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research (and a lot of compromise in the initial design), I decided to use Lovefield by Google. It is the closest to what I have been looking for since 1. it is embedded in the browser and 2. structured query is how you get data. Still hoping there would be a solution to an embedded MySQL database in an Electron app.

Comment: MySql or MariaDB aren't really suitable to be run in-process, that's what Sqlite and Redis are for, so I highly doubt anyone will bother to make MySQL run inside the browser

Comment: Actually, I _was_ thinking of putting an installer script for MySQL inside the app so it's still technically not in the app. But I have zero idea where to start so I resorted to the idea of a bundled MySQL db. Turns out it is not a good idea at all. I wonder if an embedded type of database is any better?

Comment: it is all better, an embedded database is made especially for this use case

Comment: Well, that's nice. Thanks for your insights.

Comment: @Qchmqs, is Redis a suitable alternative to Sqlite? It is the first time that I have heard that and it sounds intriguing. Have you bundled it before and the deployment went smooth? Does Redis run like a server on the user machine or like a file in sqlite? Does the user need to set permissions etc upon installation?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime in the past, I have managed to embed a full Drupal CMS installation inside of node-webkit (https://nwjs.io/). It was configured to proxy all the known PHP files to the embedded PHP installation. Then we have simply imported the sql dump file into sqlite and the entire thing worked out nicely. You might want to give that a try.

As @jd-hernandes pointed out, sqlite could be the answer you are looking for.